# python point of sys.exit

Tags: exit, sys

What is the point of exiting a program using sys.exit?  Does it not end without sys.exit at the end of the code anyway?  Or is it's purpose to immediately end program at that instance of code, in which it must be followed with break?

```
sys.exit
break
```

But why must it be followed with a break?  And what does passing `sys.exit` parameters do, like I have seen `sys.exit(2)`?  Is this some kind of error?

What is generally best practice?

Comment: help(sys.exit) is a no go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that it allows to send an error code back to the shell (or caller) and it terminates the program.
Besides, it's a function you need to call: `sys.exit()` not just `sys.exit`.
Finally, don't hesitate to read the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sys.html?highlight=sys.exit#sys.exit